# Uncaught TypeError: education[0] is undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

"
[
{
"eduTitle": "test",
"eduDescription": "test",
"eduStartDate": "03/24/23",
"eduEndDate": "03/24/23",
"_id": "641c0110cb3a9b14cf0e3030"
},
{
"eduTitle": "test",
"eduDescription": "test",
"eduStartDate": "03/24/23",
"eduEndDate": "03/24/23",
"_id": "641c0110cb3a9b14cf0e3031"
}
]
"

The above is the education

when I use `JSON.stringify(education)` I get the above, but can't get to show with `<p>{education[0]._id}</p>`

it gives `Uncaught TypeError: education[0] is undefined`

I want to display this one by one like click on next then next element appears, I tried accessing the index element but was not able to.

Comment: Please, share the code that throws the error

Comment: when i use {education[0]._id} in Html tags

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could happen when the data is not initially available.

Try this

```
<p>{education?.[0]?._id}</p>
```

or

```
<p>{Array.isArray(education) && education.length > 0 ? education[0]._id || ''}</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

You already have stringified JSON. In order to access it, you should do the reverse: instead of `JSON.stringify(education)`, you should do `JSON.parse(education)`.

Once you parse the array, you can access its elements.

```js
const education = JSON.parse(data);

console.log(education[0]?._id);
```

Comment: actually i didn't stringified it i just used it to view in page. by the way the this console.log(education[0]?._id); worked thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can not access education data like `education[0]` after `JSON.stringify(education)`,
because JSON.stringify convert your education array object to JSON string.

So after that converted, your education[0] value is `"["` because it's the string's first character, that is why you got `Uncaught TypeError: education[0]._id is undefined error`.

If you want to use that data in html element you have to use an array object without converting it to JSON.stringfy.

For more clarification about `JSON.stringyfy()` visit this link https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify